# Flask debug toolbar does not work with FlaskAPI

Tags: flask

I'm Trying to use [Flask Debug toolbar](https://github.com/mgood/flask-debugtoolbar) with [FlaskAPI](https://github.com/tomchristie/flask-api). They don't seem to play well together. Even though FlaskAPI renders responses as HTML using it's browsable API renderer, debug toolbar still doesn't show up. Does anyone have any clue as to how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

I met this problem when i integrate `flask-debugtoolbar` with `flask-security`. The output of flask debugger said: There is no `<body>` tag find in that page. After i add `<body>` tag to that page, the two extensions work together. Hope this will helpful.

Comment: There's no error. I'll probably have to go through the code and figure it out.